# Python 3.x: import a function, config dictionary, ... etc. from a file in a different directory

Tags: directory, path, python-3.6, python-import, sys

The folder tree of my project is:

```
project:
|
| -- src:
        |--- dir_a:
            |--- file_a.py
        |--- dir_b:
            |--- file_b.py
```

I want to import a function, config dictionary, ... etc. in the file_a.py (the current file) from the file_b.py

I found many answers talking about packages and modules, but I don't know anything about them because I'm writing simple python files. Moreover, I want to send this project to someone to use it on his computer (running some files .py from the command line) without editing the system path manually or any other hard solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new package that has both `dir_a` and `dir_b` in it. Then you need an empty file `__init__.py` in every directory in the package.

```
src/
  |_ pkg/
      |_ __init__.py
      |_ dir_a/
          |_ __init__.py
          |_ file_a.py
      |_ dir_b/
          |_ __init__.py
          |_ file_b.py
```

Then, provided there are no circular dependencies, in `file_a.py` you can put any of these:

```
import pkg.dir_b.file_b

# or

from pkg.dir_b.file_b import ...

# or

from pkg.dir_b import file_b
```